# Run Chainlink node for BSC main / testnet

Tags: testnets, oracles, bsc, chainlink, aws

I'm trying to get full potential of using Chainlink to interact between smart contracts and APIs and currently I'm a little stuck at running a Chainlink node for BSC main / testnet. I see in their documentation (https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/) that they provide the variables for Kovan, Rinkeby and Ethereum environments and I tried to adapt it, unsuccessfully, for the chain IDs of BSC main / testnet.

Could someone please provide me more materials on how should I get a node up and running? :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variables for BSC Mainnet are:

```
echo "ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=56
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x404460C6A5EdE2D891e8297795264fDe62ADBB75
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*" > ~/.chainlink-bscmainnet/.env
```

and for BSC Testnet:

```
echo "ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=97
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x84b9B910527Ad5C03A9Ca831909E21e236EA7b06
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*" > ~/.chainlink-bsctestnet/.env
```

To get them in the future visit [Developer Reference Page](https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/)